# Turning off IIS8 Custom Errors for Classic ASP - Potenial bug in IIS?

Tags: iis, asp-classic, custom-errors, iis-8

I think I have found a bug regarding in the IIS Error Pages system.

Note:
 - I am not using .NET Error Pages - this is set to Off

**The problem:**

When a custom error page is setup for the 500.100 (Classic ASP) response code, IIS always sends a custom error page even when **errorMode** is set to **Detailed**.  The only way to get IIS to send the error is to explicitely remove the entry in the web.config.

EG:

```
<remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100"/>
 or
<clear/>
```

Note - the following does **not** work (which works for all other codes):

```
<remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1"/>
```

**My scenario:**

- IIS 8 (I am unaware if the issue exists in older versions of IIS)
- Website running .NET 2.0 - Classic pipeline
- Feature Delegation on Error Pages set to **read only**
- Error page setup in IIS as follows (due to the feature delegation above, these entries are not in the web.config):

  - 404 - /path/to/404.htm - ExecuteURL
  - 500 - /path/to/500.htm - ExecuteURL
  - 500.100 - /path/to/500.htm - ExecuteUrl

**Turning off Custom Errors:**

In order to turn off the custom errors, all I need to do is:

- Load IIS
- Load `Error Pages`
- Click `Edit Feature Settings`
- Select `Detailed Errors`

This works successfully for all codes **except** Classic ASP 500 errors (status code 500.100).

The only way I can get the proper Classic ASP error is to setup the following (which requires me to change the feature delegation to Read/Write):

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">

        <clear/>  
        OR    
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100"/>

    </httpErrors>    
</system.webServer>
```

**Summary**

It seems that if a 500.100 custom error page is setup, then setting **Detailed Errors** to true does **not** work for Classic ASP 500 errors.

**Is this a bug or am I missing something?**

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753103%28v=ws.10%29.aspx
You can't use custom 500 error page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a known bug that we also get and are working around it by removing the 500 error and instead linking to our custom page from the "when you can find anything else  to send 'em" part of the configuration.

(I can't remenber off hand what its called)

Comment: Hi, could you point me to where this is a known bug?  I can't find anything official from MS saying so.  I'm probably looking in the wrong place! thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify your web.config in this way (it worked for me with IIS 7.5).

Replace the line

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
```

with

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" errorMode="Detailed">
```

This is because by default IIS7 intercepts HTTP status codes such as 4xx and 5xx generated by applications further up the pipeline.

Comment: This isn't actually solving the issue.  You are telling the httpErrors to not fire if an existing response exists.